# get order by string/value in product_options array

Tags: orders, magento2.2, rest-api

We are working with a third party plugin that interacts with the Magento cart process prior to an order being placed.

In that it is dealing with a product configuration that is still in a 'quote' state at the time, it doesn't have an orderId yet to reference so they issue their own Id which is eventually placed into the finished order in a json serialized key in the product_options array.

After the order is placed, we need to be able to link a response we get from their API to the actual order in the database for our fulfillment system. We were considering doing this by creating a custom Rest API within magento that the fulfillment system could query to get the remainder of the order details that are not returned by the third party app.

As a result, the fulfillment system first receives a response from the third party with a hexidecimal "Project ID" that shows up in the product_options of a finished order. We need to build the REST api to use this "Project ID" supplied in the third-party API to search for the corresponding order in which it appears and return the rest of the order options.

But I'm still somewhat new to Magento and I'm not sure if anything already exists to retrieve an order by a string match in the product_options fields/values.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up discovering the built-in restful support and while we are still working on a code based solution to handle the Oauth 1.0 credentials for it, I confirmed with postman that it will provide the kind of information we need with a 'like' search parameter on the /rest/V1/orders/items/ end point.